# opencv functions for detecting a contoured cross

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm working on a camera project with opencv, to detect the size of a box, I've got 2x line lasers set up at a different angle to the camera to show an intersecting red cross. I've kept the Red channel and keeping only the brightest before using canny() and then HoughLinesP() to easily look for the type of image in example 1, and measure its width and height.

How can I use opencv to look for depth variations on the surface, as in example 2 and 3? or rather how can i measure the result (width and height of the box) like I can in example 1.

[image: three surfaces]

The drawn examples for 2 and 3 are far more extreme than I'll be getting in the real world and are just for demonstration.

The size will vary, but the cross will always exist. The small disjointed lines, top and right, are what the background may reflect, so those need to be avoided.